# Why use Change Event triggers over existing async methods?

Tags: trigger, asynchronous, change-data-capture

When and why should we use [Change Event Triggers](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_change_event_triggers.htm) over [@future](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm) or [queueable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) methods?

Also do they use sync or asynch limits? I cannot find any clear documentation stating this.